# Can't get Eclipse to run with Java FX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Alright so basically, I'm trying to run Eclipse with JavaFX, but then it gives me this error:

> You are not running your eclipse instance with Java7 or Java8. The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java7/8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java7/8 install.
>
> In case you want to turn off this check open your preferences and go to General > Startup and Shutdown and uncheck 'JavaFX Tooling Java Check'

Now I know it isn't pointing to the right SDK, but I have no idea how to change it, since I'm kind of new to this this stuff. I've already downloaded JDK 7.40 as well. I'm also using Ubuntu on a virtual machine, if that even matters anyway. Can anyone help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://askubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the default java on your system is not java7. What do you get when opening a shell and execute java -version? Solution is to:
A) make java7 the default java
B) start eclipse with -vm

Answer (score 1):

Pre-requirements:
Install  Java™ 8.
Install Kepler SR2 (4.3.2) .
The Kepler is still not supporting Java8. What to do?
Open Eclipse
Help > Install New Software…
Enter the following URL into the ‘Work with’ field:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

Press ‘Enter’
Select category ‘Eclipse Java 8 Support (for Kepler SR2)’
Click ‘Next’
Click ‘Next’
Accept Licence Agreement
Click ‘Finish’

---

Now jre8 is correctly located.

Now configure JavaFx
Open Eclipse
Help > Install New Software…
Enter the following URL into the ‘Work with’ field:

http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/0.9.0/site

Press ‘Enter’
Select category ‘Eclipse Java 8 Support (for Kepler SR2)’
Click ‘Next’
Click ‘Next’
Accept Licence Agreement
Click ‘Finish’

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have installed 32bit Eclipse and 64bit JRE/JDK on a 64bit OS. Please use 64bit Eclipse and the problem will be solved. Please make sure JAVA_HOME And JRE_HOME is present in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I tried re-installing Eclipse, but it wouldn't work. I had to completely remove the project and delete all the project files. After that, I re-started eclipse and created the project again.  However, this time I made sure the project path included the Java FX library as shown in the screen shot.
[Java Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueg1o.png)

I did this while I was creating the project and then I was able to create the project without any issues.  Give this a try.